# kafka won't connect with logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

i am trying to connect kafka to logstash using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html

I have the kafka and zookeeper running,(i've verified this by creating a producer and consumer in python), but logstash won't detect kafka,

I have installed the kafka input plug-in, this is what my conf file looks like :

```
    input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["divolte-data"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "divolte-data"
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you could show us, if there're any errors? And what's the version of `ES` &` `Kafka` you're using?

Comment: I have tried kafka 0.9 and and kafka .10 , es is 2.3 .. I created cosumer in python and pushed the data to a tcp port using sockets, and set the logstash to pick up the data form that port and it's working.

Comment: There wasn't any error, logstash started just fine but wasn't able to consume any messages from kafka.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Sure .. thanks man.. The force is strong with you .

Comment: Haha I'm always with the force. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the version. Since you're running on `ES 2.3`, it's not compatible to use `bootstrap_servers` within your **kafka** input plugin, which was introduced from the version of [5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-zk_connect).

As per the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/plugins-inputs-kafka.html), you should be using [zk_connect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-zk_connect) instead of `bootstrap_servers`, like this:

```
kafka {
   zk_connect => "localhost:9092"
}
```